# Storing local data

Tags: apache-flex

I am deploying a desktop application using AIR, and I would like to store some user-specific data on the machine such as a history of his entries. Is this possible? Where can I learn more about this?
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://blog.crankybit.com/notes-adobe-air-local-data-storage-options/) blog tells what all options you have for local data storage using AIR. Select one which best fits your needs and [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/)(Adobe Help site) will contain a good explanation of them along with examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples in the Air version of [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour) for how do this.